# Как организовать правильную структуру сайта?

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Я еще новичок и не знаю как правильно организовать структуру сайта. Какие файлы где должны находиться и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настоящее время зачастую балом правят фреймворки и, скорее всего, файловую структуру фронтенд части вашего приложения зададут именно они это же, как правило, применимо и к бэкенду.

Comment: Я смотрел здесь какой должна быть правильная структура сайта
https://domhtml.ru/struktura-sajta-seo/

Все наглядно и понятно

Answer (score 3):

Хорошо спланированная структура сайта повышает ваши шансы хорошего ранжирования результатах Google.
Планирование архитектуры вашего сайта - его навигации и его логику - и знания ключевых слов, на которые будет ориентирован ваш сайт - всё это имеет решающее значение для ваши шансы на привлечение релевантного трафика.
На самом деле, архитектура вашего сайта - путь связи страниц друг с другом - должны быть ключевой частью вашего бизнес-планирования. Это довольно важно.
Юзабилити - это помощь пользователям найти быстро (с наименьшим количеством кликов - максимум 3 клика) то, что они хотят.
Удобство и простота использования сайта является обязательным условием, как для поисковых систем и так и для пользователей. 
Исследования ключевых слов может сказать вам, что заинтересует пользователей вашего сайта. Поэтому используйте эти знания для планирования вашего сайта.
Создайте содержание отдельных страниц (или страниц продукта) для целевых ключевых слов, которые вы определили для темы вашего сайта. Вы можете создавать темы для разных категорий. Веб-сканеры Googlebot будут сканировать структуру вашего веб-сайта. Их цель состоит в том, чтобы индексировать содержание, и, чтобы вернуть его в результатах поиска (поисковой выдаче). Понятная структура сайта поможет поисковым системам понять весь ваш веб-сайт и поможет пользователям найти то, что они ищут.
Итак:

- Исследуйте ваши целевые ключевые слова, прежде чем принять решение о вашей структуре сайта
- Используйте результаты этого исследования ключевых слов, чтобы определить, какие ключевые слова вы установите на вашей главной странице, странице категорий (каталог), страницы продукта и сообщений в блоге
- Создайте плоскую структуру ссылок - максимум 3 клика от главной страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Вам очень сильно поможет [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) он не только поможет вам правильно организовать папки, но и правильно организовать структуру верстки (посмотрите на grid). Можно также если хотите ставить дополнительные модули использовать [bower](http://bower.io).

Дальше советую смотреть в сторону [yeoman.io](http://yeoman.io/)